# Is there way to know if skinny table is Enabled in SF org?

Tags: soql, tooling-api, skinny-table

I wanted to check if any information is available via `SOQL-tooling API` or is there any flag or some sought of information available VIA `API` or anything which will tell me by looking into salesforce org that , this particular org has skinny table enabled.

Comment: Not aware of a flag but you can hack this by measuring the performance (elapsed time) of a SOQL query that would hit the skinny table (if it were there). You can then compare expected vs actual. You can do this as a unit test or a non-test piece of code. Assuming the difference in performance is large enough, this test would be implemented as a threshold check. If elapsed time is < 1s (for example), skinny table is present.

Comment: It may well show up in the query plan tool. Could be worth a quick test.